# Exported APK name

Tags: android, apk

Does anyone know how to solve this issue? Lets say I have application MyApp and I've exported it into three APK files

1.MyApp_1.apk,

2.MyApp_2.apk,

3.MyApp_3.apk.

Lets say all those apks are slightly different (it matters not).Is there a way to get **which apk was installed** to device *(this is needed in runtime)*: MyApp_1.apk or MyApp_2.apk, or MyApp_3.apk?

Thank you :)

Answer (score 2):

AFAIK You cannot get the difference but what you can do is change the version number of each apk in Manifest and get the version number using

```
    PackageInfo info =getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(getPackageName(), 0);
    info.versionName;
```

Comment: So I cannot get the "MyApp_1.apk" in runtime? (Package and version code are unchanged)

Comment: I dont think you can do it, because as soon as you install the installer changes the name of apk in the format [packagename]-[randomnumber].apk .

Answer (score 0):

You can only check which version currently installed. If you install same app via 3 different apks, you can't detect the APK file names.

Please refer the the answer given by nandeesh

Comment: I would install one of these apk, but in application (for some reasons) I would like to know which apk is that